# What is this math problem asking for?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have a problem with a problem. I don't know how it is asking me to proceed, even though I know how to do it any which way. I just need to understand what the english means!

**Problem: Determine the values of $t$ that would make the following derivative to become singular.**

$$
        \frac{d}{dt}\left(\begin{matrix}
        (t+2)^2 & t-5 & 4t \\
        3 & 2-t & t \\
        20 & 5 & t^3 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

**Question:** Is the problem asking for me to

1. Take the derivative, compute the determinant, and find $t$ such that the determinant equals zero ($t=0,-2$)?

OR

1. Compute the determinant and set it equal to a constant, such that taking the derivative of that expression will cause the derivative to become singular?

OR

1. Take the derivative of the determinant, for which an independent formula would have to be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The English in the quoted problem statement is rather poor. If I had to guess, I would say your first choice is the correct one. The other two are most likely incorrect.

The ambiguity in the statement is that it refers to "the following derivative" with no indication that any differentiation has occurred. So my only question would be whether the matrix presented *already is* a derivative or not. The author probably should have said "Determine the values of $t$ for which the derivative of the following is singular."

Answer (score 0):

Your first suggestion is how I would read the problem.  I didn't check your work, but that is how I would interpret a singular derivative.